# how to add custom css to a library component in angular?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 9.0 with material design.

In a component, I would like to use `<mat-tab-group>` and style the array to be a certain color and design.

I know 2 ways :

1. using `::ng-deep` but now deprecated
2. using global `css` stylesheet but apply it everywhere

I want to do this ONLY on the tab contained in that component.

````
  <mat-tab label="myList">
    <div>
      <app-lister-search></app-lister-search> 
    </div>
    <div>
      <app-lister></app-lister> 
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>```

this will generate some component, and I want to apply css to some of them, but they is not possible to add this in the component css as it it outside of the scope.

How can I achieve this ?
````

Comment: view encapsulation + css only for that component.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you from placing your styles in the "main" stylesheet and applying it only to tab-groups with specific class:

Template:

```
<mat-tab-group class="my-tab-group">
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

styles.scss:

```
.my-tab-group {
  background-color: orange;

  .mat-tab-label {
    padding: 5em;

    &-active {
      background-color: green;
    }
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqxoeg)

Comment: you right, but I believe this is a polluting solution

Comment: You should have specified that in your question then. This IS a working solution that allows you to do what you asked for.
If you don't like it this way - place it in the component's .css / .scss file and use `ViewEncapsulation.None` 
Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#encapsulation)